# "Ask for" VS "ask about" homework

Tags: prepositions

If I want to recommend that a friend ask her private tutor to give her homework (because her tutor isn't used to assigning her any homework), what should I say? I want to use a short sentence (not "ask your tutor to give you homework"). I know that you should use "ask for" if you want to request some information. so, does homework fall under this category of info? Or should I use "ask about homework" instead?

Sentences:

> Ask your tutor for homework so you can practice in between classes.
> Then, ask for homework!

Comment: You can _ask for_ anything, not just information! (Forgiveness, another cup of tea, something on sale in a shop...)

Comment: For what it's worth, “Ask your tutor to give you homework” would seem perfectly natural in the circumstances — it doesn't sound unnecessarily long.  In fact, I'd be more likely to _add_ a word: “Ask your tutor to give you _some_ homework.”

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can say things like

> Ask your tutor for homework . . .
> Ask your tutor for more homework . . .

And this is probably the shortest, most direct way to ask for something, including homework.

As you have surmised, you may also ask in one of these ways:

> Ask your tutor about homework . . .
> Ask your tutor about more homework . . .
> Ask your tutor about giving you some more homework . . .
> Ask your tutor about the possibility of giving you some more homework . . .

What these last 3 versions are saying (without really saying it) is that your friend should be especially polite when she makes the request. So naturally, they are longer. You're communicating the instruction in a roundabout manner so that she will make the request in a roundabout manner.

Only you or your friend knows how much politeness is required by the situation.

As to your other suggestion, it is grammatically correct to say **Then ask for some homework.** It would be more *idiomatically* correct to say, **Then ask for *some* homework.** English strongly favors the use of articles and other determiners, especially when the noun in question is tangible or can be perceived that way—here, as a set of pages, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
One more question. Is it grammatically correct to say "Then, ask for homework!" in a conversation with my friend?

Comment: It is grammatically correct. It would be more idiomatically correct to say, "Then ask for *some* homework." English strongly favors the use of articles and other determiners, especially when the noun in question is tangible or can be perceived that way—here, as a set of pages, perhaps.